# Why parent div isn't getting expected height

Tags: html, css

I've implemented a template with static heights. I've changed it's content height to fit to child heights, but parent `<main>` and parent `<section>` aren't getting the autocalculated height. 
Why?
I'm getting insane with this issue.

HTML:

```
<section class="seccion-productos">
  <div id="sidebar">...</div>
  <div id="grid-selector">...</div>
  <div id="grid">...</div>
</section>
</main>
<footer>...</footer>
```

[image: html code]

CSS:

```
#sidebar{
    float: none;
    height: auto;
    width: 22%;
    padding: 1% 0 0 2%;
}
.seccion-productos { 
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
#grid-selector {
    width: 78%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 22%;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#grid {
    width: 78%;
    height: auto;
    top: 90px;
    left: 22%;
}
```

Undesired Result, parent content doesn't fit child content
[image: Result]
[image]

I am just asking what things can make this happen and what should I do to solve it. Or if i'm missing something. Or where I have to look.

You also can see full code in here:
https://randal-es.000webhostapp.com/php/paginas/productos.php

Comment: Screenshots of code snippets is not allowed in StackOverflow. Please write your HTML code snippet in the question itself.

Comment: I've added also as html, just forgot it

Comment: I just review your code and there are few code structure issues, You are using `position: absolute` on `grid-selector` and `grid` element, it's not a right way align element to right or left. I would suggest first resolve your code structure issues. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Arngue, as @Johannes says, if you put a child element with absolute positioning it won't affect the parent element even if the parent element has position relative. The only thing that the parent's relative position affects is the origin of coordinates for absolute positioning. You need to change the position definition for `#grid-selector` otherwise it will always break your layout.

Answer (score 1):

The `position: absolute;` of the `#grid-selector` element takes it out of the size calculation context for the parent. Change that to `relative`

Comment: That not works, is it absolute because .seccion-productos is relative

Comment: in this case it's better to use the display `flex` and remove `position:absolute` check [css style](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thanks @FarshadFahimi, when i've studied css flex just don't exists yet